# Flask Login system

Tags: python, html, flask

I've just started with flask development and wanted to know if I am going about it the right way.

I basically want to build a login page with Flask.

What I understand is:

1. Make the webapp using flask. I serve the HTML template which is actually my login page.
2. The user enters the details in the login form.

Where do I go from here? How do I proceed? I have the username and the password but how do I check the credentials from a database?

The code that I have is given below:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return render_template('hello.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is the flask file code. The HTML code is given below:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="login" method="post">
            Username:<input type="text" name=username required placeholder="Username"><br>
            Password:<input type="password" name=pwd required placeholder="Password"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
        <button 
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I proceed?

I am sorry that I am naive on both the web-dev part and flask but both are new to me.

Comment: Did you read [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#the-request-object) docs fully?

Comment: Doing just that. I've reached the render template part. Thus decided to try some basics out. Like load a web page from flask and get information from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#the-request-object) docs we need simply create a Login method like

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if valid_login(request.form['username'],
                       request.form['password']):
            return log_the_user_in(request.form['username'])
        else:
            error = 'Invalid username/password'
    # the code below is executed if the request method
    # was GET or the credentials were invalid
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

and need little change in your html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="login" method="post" action='/login'>
            Username:<input type="text" name=username required placeholder="Username"><br>
            Password:<input type="password" name=password required placeholder="Password"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain what the code does? Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: Did you see `submit` input in your html form. What its duty is to submit a form data where the `action` url is. Here I put `action` url as `/login`, so we need to handle that form submission in server side that is `def login` function did.

Comment: Okay. SO far so good. Basically, the html page will send a POST request to the server and I can access it using the `request.username` part of the code. The only problem is on running the code I get the error:

`NameError: name 'valid_login' is not defined`

This method is to be used to identify the user/validate the credentials. Where do I define this so that it works properly?

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava you boy, `valid_login` is a function who carries our login mechanism like check `username` and `password` with `database` or any other `services`. You need to define it.

Comment: I realized that and did define it. Thanks. Sorry for not updating here. Sorry.